# Changing screen settings in windows 10 with one click

Tags: settings, display, profile

I use three screens on my windows 10 desktop. The main screen is 1920x1200. My laptop has 1920x1080 on its only screen. I remote control my desktop from my laptop, and I change the display settings to disable the two other screens and set the resolution of my main screen to match that of my laptop. It's somewhat tedious to change those settings, so **I am looking for a way to change my display settings all at once**.

Essentially I wish to have two profiles: 1 for regular use, and 2 for remote control. As far as I have researched, one cannot change display settings in windows 10 from the command line, so a simple bat file is not possible.

What is a way of achieving this switch with as few clicks as possible?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use PowerShell with the cmdlet `Set-DisplayResolution`.

The documentation about this cmdlet you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servercore/set-displayresolution?view=win10-ps)

Comment: Does this work for changing resolutions on local machines?